# How to add folder to a $Resource in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, static-resources

How could I add a folder into `$Resource`?

I know that this is possible for example from over:

[here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_resource_value_provider.htm) : `scripts="{!join(',', 
    $Resource.jsLibraries + '/jsLibOne.js', 
    $Resource.jsLibraries + '/jsLibTwo.js')}"` - the folder name in the case is `jsLibraries`;

[here](https://sfcure.com/2018/05/14/how-to-create-charts-using-d3-library-in-lightning-components/) : `scripts="{!join(',', 
    $Resource.d3Libraries+ '/jquery.min.js', 
    $Resource.d3Libraries+ '/d3.v4.min.js')}"` - the folder name in the case is `d3Libraries`.

So, now I try to apply my knowledge of the salesforce and check the places where I would expect the folder creation to appear:

I check the `Static Resources` from the setup `Quick Find`. The only options I have are to add a view (the purpose of which I was not able to find at all) or to add a file (but not a folder as I want).
[image]

I check the developer console. And now I am able to create only an ordinary file (but again not a folder as I want).

[image]

So, where can I find the folder addition into the `$Resource`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The folder is actually just a ZIP file. In the Developer Console, there's no way to make such a resource. You'd either upload it in Setup after creating the ZIP file, or for a nicer experience, you can use DX, which decomposes the ZIP into the files so you can manipulate them individually and push the changes.